# How can I use variables of Form1 in Form2 in C#?

Tags: c#, forms, global-variables

I have an array of strings in Form1 and I want to display it's items in a treeview of Form2. How can I use Form1's variables in Form2? What would be the simplest solution here?

Comment: have you tried static variables?

Answer (score 0):

You could pass it thru the constructor.

**PSEUDO**

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private string[] _myArray;
    private Form2 _form2;

    public Form1()
    {
        _myArray = new string[3];
        _myArray[0] = "Hi";
        _myArray[1] = "There";
        _myArray[2] = "Test";

        _form2 = new Form2(_myArray);
        _form2.Show();
    }
 }

public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    private string[] _myArrayOfForm2;

    public Form2(string[] myArr)
    {
        _myArrayOfForm2 = myArr;
        BuildTree(); 
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The most flexible yet easy way to do this that comes to my mind would be to set the variables you need in Form1 (in this case the string array) as **public** and then pass the entire Form as an argument in the constuctor, like this:

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
    public Form2(Form1 _form) {
    // code goes here
    }
}
```